# invitation_accepted? returns FALSE in after_invitation_accepted CALLBACK

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, ruby-on-rails-6, devise-invitable

[image]I use devise_invitable (2.0.6)

invitation_accepted? returns FALSE in after_invitation_accepted CALLBACK but when I pause here and check in rails console it gives me true for invitation_accepted?

user.rb

```
after_invitation_accepted :create_something

def create_something
  create_service unless invitation_sent_at? && !invitation_accepted?  
end
```

here, invitation_accepted? is false inside this callback but, when I pause here and check in rails console it gives me true

Did I miss anything??

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/

Comment: @smathy question is updated with code

Comment: Show the console session showing whatever "when I pause here and check" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is comment right above the [`invitation_accepted?`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/92e085e32e7e8537cc38e718e6710d408068d3c2/lib/devise_invitable/models.rb#L129) in the source code:

```
# Verifies whether a user accepted an invitation (false when user is accepting it)
def invitation_accepted?
  !accepting_invitation? && invitation_accepted_at.present?
end
```

That means `invitation_accepted?` is not `true` while the user is accepting the invitation, but only after the user accepted the invitation.

When looking at what the implementation of [`accept_invitation!`](https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/92e085e32e7e8537cc38e718e6710d408068d3c2/lib/devise_invitable/models.rb#L93) then we see that `@accepting_invitation` is set to `true` in the method before the invitation is accepted, but it is not set to `false` after the record in the database was updated.

What means only after re-loading the user from the database `invitation_accepted?` will return `true`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. 
So no need to check the condition inside the callback because its a callback of after_invitation_accepted.

Comment: Exactly, the `after_invitation_accepted` callback is only called, right after the invitation was accepted and when this acceptance was successfully written to the database. If the acceptance wasn't saved because there was, for example, a validation error then the callback will not be called.